# What would make my apple seedling wilt and looks like it's dying?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, seeds, seedlings, apples

I have a little apple sapling that I planted using a seed from an apple at the super market. I live in Auckland, New Zealand and my apple sapling is about 10 cm (4 in) tall. Recently it became very limp. I tried giving it more water, less water; more sun, less sun. I've kept it indoors and outdoors in both the shade and the sun. None of these things have improved its condition. What should I do?

Comment: A photograph would be useful, but failing that, is this plant in a pot and if so, how big's the pot and how long's it been in the same pot?

Comment: Welcome to the site Hannah! By any chance can you post a picture for us? Also, in addition to Bamboo's questions, what kind of soil is in the pot? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since your apple tree seedling doesn't respond to changes in watering, and you're not describing an infestation of the leaves, then it's most likely you have a root problem.  Suggest you remove the seedling from the pot and see if the roots are rotting from previous over watering or an infection.